# Platformer Game: Character Falling Too Fast

Tags: c#, xna

Ok, so I have this platformer game that has blocks and lava, and a character.  Please keep in mind that I am a 13-year-old, and am not super experienced with C# (I've been using C# and .NET for about 8 months). This is the code that I have for detecting the blocks:

```
bool onGround = false
const int G = 5;
foreach (Block block in blocks)
{
      while (!(characterRectangle.Intersects(block.Rectangle)))
      {
          location.Y += G;
          break;
      }

      onGround = characterRectangle.Intersects(block.Rectangle);
}
```

The problem? The character is falling too fast. The more blocks there are, the faster it falls. Now, I know that this is because of the foreach loop, but what is the solution to this.

Comment: Perhaps `if (!blocks.Any(block => characterRectangle.Intersects(block.Rectangle)))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most games wouldn't move their player down, as if with gravity, during the collision detection phase. Instead, move the player down before the collision-detection loop. Then, if during your collision-detection, you find he is colliding with something, move him **back up** until he no longer collides.

Check out http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html, a goldmine :).

Answer (score 0):

When does this code get called?

The first thing I noticed:
The "while" loop is more or less useless, since you always call `break;`. This will exit the while loop. You might aswell use an "if" clause.

Also, what is "location"? Is this your player location? If yes, then it's Y-Value will be increased by G for every Block that's in `blocks`. Therefore your player will fall faster the more blocks are in that `blocks` collection.